# Lower memory usage and speed nested loops

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, memory

I'm trying to make some tracking with *Mathematica*.

```
ff[x_, y_] := 
  NestList[
    {{Cos[0.1], 2.0 Sin[0.1]}, {-0.5 Sin[0.1], Cos[0.1]}}.# + 
        {0, RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}]} &, 
    {x, y}, 
    100000
  ][[;; ;; 100]]
xy = Outer[ff, Range[-1, 1, 0.02], Range[-0.1, 0.1, 0.002]];
```

So, I have some mapping rules (one-turn matrix in this example) for 2D vector of initial values and then I want to calculate such map for many particles during many turns keeping information for every turn (that's why using NestList). In this example I'm going to use 101*101 ~ 10000 particles and 100000 turns, but this can't be done. *Mathematica* eats all my memory (8 GB of RAM, and pagefile as well) and takes much time to run, so I have to add `[[;; ;; 100]]` to definition of `ff[]` and hence to keep information on every 100th turn only.

What can be done, if possible, to lower memory consumption of such nested constructions: store data in more compact form, or some compression?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Usually it is not necessary to store all particle trajectories. What is your final goal? May be some averaged value?

Comment: That is an abstract simple example. I want to know if it is possible to work in Mathematica with big nested arrays (lists of matrices). On  the other hand, to make averaging over turns (or particles) we need to know all the turns for all the particles, I guess.

Comment: I don't think the issue here is language specific. Any system that is working with that amount of data will use a similar amount of memory. What about saving results to file every 1000 particles or so?

Comment: Thank you for advice, I've tried this method. E.g., run all the particles for ~1000 turns, the result is written in a file. The last record of that file is new initials for next 1000 turns. But it takes significant amount of time - writing to a file, then reading and taking Last record.

Comment: I ask because I remember some advertisings when Mma 6 (or 8, don't remeber exactly) came out, that from now it can store and operate with huge data, more than amount of RAM.

Comment: I suspect that refers to the 64-bit builds. Yes, some of the previous bounds are no longer in effect, but I would still expect a speed hit if computations start swapping pages to/from disk.